# Вопрос по шаблонизатору Twig

Tags: twig, база-данных, php

Здравствуйте, вывожу из базы данных следующий текст:

```
Сам текст {{ pages.name }}
```

В шаблоне `twig` вывожу его так

```
{{ pages.text }}
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы метка `{{ pages.name }}` выводилась не просто как текст, а как метка шаблона и выводила бы свое значение, возможно ли?

Comment: никто не знает? *up*

Comment: Сформулируйте ваш вопрос в более понятной форме

Comment: А что не понятного)? в базе хоронятся метки типа {{ pages.name }}, когда я вывожу их на страницу они так и пишутся, но это ведь теги Twig'a они должны форматироваться в перменные. Вместе {{ pages.name }} должно вывестись название данной страницы. Я думаю если бы мой пост был не понятен, хекшкод бы его отредактировал

Answer (score 1):

Используйте **template_from_string** ([документация](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html))

```
{{ include(template_from_string("{{pages.name}}")) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можешь попробовать передать его как шаблон, а потом отрендить